# Pouch DB - Created database - Saved under _id - Trying to retrieve later change data and resave

Tags: get, save, put, doc

Created a database, saved a doc. Retrieved doc, edited doc, trying to .put back doc with new values.

I am retrieving but coming back NaN

```
var TotalDrills;
TotalDrills = new PouchDB(currentDB);

var doc = {
"_id": "DrillCount",
"TotalDrillCount": 0.0,
"_rev": success._rev,
};
TotalDrills.put(doc);



TotalDrills.get("DrillCount", function (failure, success) {
if (failure) {
console.log("Error getting Drill: " + failure); }  
else {
console.log("TotalDrills database TotalDrillsQuantity id 
Successfully got Drill: " + success);
TotalDrillsCount = success.TotalDrillCount;
TotalDrillsCount = parseInt(TotalDrillsCount);
console.log(TotalDrillsCount);
console.log("just .val: " + TotalDrillsCount);
}
});
console.log("TotalDrillsCount: " + TotalDrillsCount);

</code>
```